# python regex reading parts of text file

Tags: python, regex

I'm having a `.txt` file that look like

```
'type': 'validation', 'epoch': 91, 'loss': tensor(294.8862,      device='cuda:0'), 'acc': tensor(1.00000e-02 *
   9.9481), 'kl': tensor(292.5818, device='cuda:0'), 'likelihood': tensor(-2.3026, device='cuda:0')}{'type': 'train', 'epoch': 92, 'loss': tensor(51.1491, device='cuda:0'), 'acc': tensor(1.00000e-02 *
   9.9642), 'kl': tensor(48.8444, device='cuda:0'), 'likelihood': tensor(-2.3026, device='cuda:0')}
```

I would like to read out the `acc` to plot it. What is wrong with my code here?

```
    acc = list(map(lambda x: x.split(" ")[-1], re.findall(r"(acc: \d.\d+)", file)))

    print(re.findall(r"(acc: \d.\d+)", file))

    train = acc[0::3]
    valid = acc[1::3]
    return np.array(train).astype(np.float32), np.array(valid).astype(np.float32)
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You file looks like JSON. I think you should be using the json module .

Comment: @Rakesh: does not look like JSON at all. Wrong quotes and bad values.

Comment: @MikeScotty. Yes you are right...

Comment: @Felix Laumann Can you post your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the values for `acc` try.

```
import re

acc = []
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    acc = re.findall(r"'acc':\s+tensor\((.*?)\)", infile.read())
print(acc)
```

**Output:**

```
['1.00000e-02 *9.9481', '1.00000e-02 *9.9642']
```

*Or if you just need the float values use.*

```
acc = [float(i.split("*")[-1].strip()) for i in acc]
print(acc) # -->[9.9481, 9.9642]
```

Comment: Maybe point out in more detail that the regex `acc: \d` looks for a space and a digit after `acc:` and there are no occurrences of this pattern in the example. Similarly, `\d\.\d+` only looks for sequences of digits on both sides of a dot, where only one digit is allowed before the dot; this obviously cannot match numbers bigger than or equal to 10, negative numbers, or numbers in exponential/scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression is wrong...

In the file it's `'acc'` while you look for `acc:`
also between `'acc':` and the numerical values is `tensor( ... )`

Try:
    `('acc': tensor\(.+?\))`